# jest error TS18047 "object is possible null"

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I'm writing a test (jtest) for an angular component, but is failing because of this error.
any idea? :)

---

```
it("should require valid email", () => {
    spectator.component.email.setValue({ email: "invalidemail" });
    expect(spectator.component.email).toEqual(false);
});
```

---

from my .ts file:

```
get email(): AbstractControl | null {
    return this.form.get("email");
}
```

and my error:

[error stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htHB4.png)

I've tried this `spectator.component.email("invalidemail");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you `this.form` is undefined. So you have to init it first:

```
it("should require valid email", () => {
    spectator.component.form = new FormGroup({email: new FormControl()});
    spectator.component.email.setValue({ email: "invalidemail" });
    expect(spectator.component.email).toEqual(false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! still I have an error, with your suggest for this spectator.component.email.setValue({ email: "invalidemail" });  then "spectator.component.email.." is possibly null  :/

Comment: You may add a null-safe-operator: `spectator.component.email?.setValue`

Comment: reading again your OP, I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Shouldn't you set the value this way instead `setValue({"invalidemail)` ? Also, what is your `expect` expecting ? The email will never be false, because it is a FormControl, and you just set its value. Are you trying to check is the input is `valid` instead ? `expect(spectator.component.email?.invalid).toEqual(true);`

Answer (score 0):

well it's resolved...

```
it("should be invalid email when invalid pattern", () => {
    spectator.detectChanges();
    spectator.component.form.get("email")?.setValue("invalidemail");
    spectator.component.form.get("email")?.updateValueAndValidity();

    expect(spectator.component.email?.invalid).toBeTruthy();
    expect(spectator.component.email?.hasError("pattern")).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

that is working for me now, thank you anyway :)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**